# change apache root folder on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up some docker containers to work with a laravel project, It's working but not on the desired folder, to acces  I have to type localhost:81/public  instead localhost:81, how I have to set up  docker to access using localhost:81?

this is **docker-compose**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_MODE: "develop,debug"
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "client_host=host.docker.internal start_with_request=yes"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: my_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_password
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

this is **Dockerfile**

```
# Imagen base de PHP 8.1 con Apache y Xdebug 3
FROM php:8.1-apache

# Instalar dependencias de Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.1 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Instalar dependencias de PHP y extensiones necesarias
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_mysql zip

# Configuración de Xdebug
RUN echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

# Habilitar módulo de Apache para el archivo .htaccess
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Exponer el puerto 9003 para Xdebug
EXPOSE 9003

# Directorio de trabajo en el contenedor
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copiamos el contenido de la aplicación al contenedor
COPY . /var/www/html

# Copiar archivo de configuración de Apache
COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Iniciar el servidor Apache y PHP
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

and this is **apache-config.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your configuration is using the default apache2 configuration in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

By default apache2 only listen on port 80 with the default DocumentRoot /var/www/html/, that's why you need to add public to reach your folder even with your configuration.

Also in your docker-compose file you map port 81 of your computer with port 80 of the docker container (The default apache2, not your vhost on port 81)

So first you need to tell apache2 to listen on port 81, since you vhost is configured like that.

You can add the `Listen 81`directory in your **apache-config.conf**

```
Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you need to map the correct port in your **docker-compose**

```
    ports:
      - "81:81"
```

Don't forget to rebuild your image, now it should be ok, you should be able to access your website using `localhost:81`

Hope this helps !